# Regular expression: Preceding token is not quantifiable

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a regular expression `(-|+)?`, but when I ran it on regex101.com I get the error:

```
+: Preceding token is not quantifiable
```

What does the error mean? Thank you

Comment: you have to escape them `(\-|\+)?`. The `+` is a metacharacter

Answer (score 6):

`+` is a special character, a quantifier, that specifies the multiplicity of the element before. For example `a+` means that there should be at least one `a`, up to any number of `a`s. If you want to match the plus character itself, you will have to escape it:

```
(-|\+)?
```

In your case, as you are only considering two different characters, you can also use a character class and specify the two characters that way. Then you don’t need to escape it:

```
[-+]?
```

Comment: As a warning to future readers: You don't absolutely need to in the second regex, but I would still recommend escaping `-`, as putting a character before it will result in it behaving as a range (e.g. `[*-+]` would only match `*` and `+`).